# How to load content from other page in index page with using url variable

Tags: php

I am trying to lad content from page1.php, page2.php and page3.php with the help of url varibale in my index page.

Here is my index page code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello there></h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php?page=page1.php">page 1</a>page1</li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=page2.php">page 2</a>page2</li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=page3.php">page 3</a>page3</li>
</ul>
<?php
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $pages = array('page1', 'page2', 'page3');
    if (!empty($page)) {
        if(in_array($page,$pages)) {

            include($page);
        }
        else {
        echo 'Page not found. Return to
        <a href="index.php">index</a>';
        }
    }
    else {
        include('page1.php');
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

the index page shows undefined variable $page

Comment: $page will get you pagex.php and you are checking it with pagex in inarray what is the value in $page.

Comment: If you are going to do this method you should just do `page=1` then check if `'page'.$_GET['page'].'.php'` is a file

Comment: when you visit index.php the key 'page'  is not set in your $_GET array.  if you want to avoid that notice you will want to check isset($_GET['page']) before assigning it to $page

Comment: check my ans nishant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `array('page1.php', 'page2.php', 'page3.php');` or avoid `.php` extension from url aswell as array and use `$page.".php"` in `include`. Also make sure that `$_GET['page'];` is set

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello there></h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php?page=page1.php">page 1</a>page1</li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=page2.php">page 2</a>page2</li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=page3.php">page 3</a>page3</li>
</ul>
<?php
    $page = isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:'page1.php';
    $pages = array('page1.php', 'page2.php', 'page3.php');
    if (!empty($page)) {
        if(in_array($page,$pages)) {

            include($page);
        }
        else {
        echo 'Page not found. Return to
        <a href="index.php">index</a>';
        }
    }
    else {
        include('page1.php');
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a routing system from a framework.

Aside from that your $_GET variable: index.php?page=page1.php is returning the string "page1.php" which doesn't exist in your $pages array. Add the .php into your $pages array and you should have it working.

Recommendations for routing systems: 
http://silex.sensiolabs.org/

Uses symfonys routing and request components. Will save you some headaches.

Comment: okkk. My array contains page1.php, page2.php and page3.php.It is working fine but on index.php page it still shows Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\mynew\index.php on line 12

Comment: Php Notices can be disabled in the ini file, but the notice is being thrown because you're attempting to pull an member of an array that doesn't exist: like page4.php. I'd double check to make sure no funny business is happening in-relation to your arrays.

Comment: More information on php errors, warning, notices : http://pc-freak.net/blog/turn-php-notices/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello there></h1>
<ul>
```

> **change page1.php to page1** beacuse in array there is no page1.php it's only page1.....

```
<li><a href="index.php?page=page1">page 1</a>page1</li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=page2">page 2</a>page2</li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=page3">page 3</a>page3</li>
</ul>
<?php
```

> you got undefine index because first time when page load $_GET['page'] doesn't exit.you need to check wether $_GET['page'] is set or not

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $pages = array('page1', 'page2', 'page3');
    if (!empty($page)) {
        if(in_array($page,$pages)) {
```

> here $page only contain page1,page2...else so you need to concate with ".php"

```
            include($page.".php");
        }
        else {
        echo 'Page not found. Return to
        <a href="index.php">index</a>';
        }
    }
    else {
        include('page1.php');
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```